# Resizing components one by one javafx fxml

Tags: javafx, fxml

I can't seem to find a way to make components resize one by one in a specific order, since all containers seem to shrink them all at once. Is there a property that can do this or do i need to use some other way.
Thanks.

```
<HBox>
<CustomControl />    
<CustomControl />
<CustomControl />
</HBox>
```

Basically when i resize the window by drag i need to resize these custom controls one after the other from right to left.

Comment: To me, this seems like something that needs to be done using `JavaFX` [`Animation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/package-summary.html). [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/jfxpub-animations.htm) are some tutorials.

Comment: @Sedrick I'm not sure this is about animating the resizing. To me it seems like the OP is asking to keep the children at their preferred sizes until the there's not enough room for all of those. Then start shrinking one child to it's min size first, after this shrinking another one and the next one in a specific order which btw is not possible using `HBox`'s layout parameters alone, since there are just 3 grow priorities: `NEVER`, `SOMETIMES` and `ALWAYS`...

Comment: @fabian got ya. After reading your comment, I read the question again. I think you are correct.

Comment: @Sedrick Yes, exactly what i'm looking for. If it's not possible with HBox what container would i need to use?

Comment: @Meidara or rather what container would i need to use inside the custom control to allow this behaviour since now its a VBox. (This behaviour should be set inside the control)